# Installed modules in Conda Environment are not working

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda, python-venv

I am trying to get Pytorch running in my Conda Environment 'llm_tut'.

When running the Verification code for pytorch from a .py file, I receive the 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'' Error.

But when I am in the environment and run the command 'conda list' pytorch is listed as an installed package in that environment.

Trying to install the package gives following result

```
conda install -n llm_tut pytorch 
Channels:
 - defaults
 - pytorch
Platform: osx-arm64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

The Error occurs regardless the package. 'requests' appears also in the list but triggers the same Error when I try to import it.

Specs are:

- Apple M2 MacBook Air
- Python 3.11 (due to Pytorch specs)
- VS Code

Comment: Did you activate your environment before trying to run the code?